# Old Cobol software and new operating system

Tags: cobol, aix

A mid aged man developed software for the company he works before about 25 years ago...
He has written everything in COBOL...It took me hours to understand how the system works!
Well the company's server is too old (8 mb hard disk ) i think ...
He doesnt use a database but stores the data in files...
He told me that he wants to upgrade the system to something new... The old system uses AIX operating system....
He was  wondering whether aix or linux is better ,i think that a distribution of linux might be better because there is much free software for linux... i dont know what is compatible for AIX...
The company is some type of warehouse...
He has developed a website for the clients to login and see some info ..The website is at remote server and he manualy copies and pastes the database at the remote server...

He wants to add the functionality to the web site of placing orders...
However he isnt willing to update the old COBOL code and use a database at least...

The people in the company  use the server's programms via telneting the server using somekind of telnet client....

My question for educational purposes...
Is there any way to reuse the COBOL code and creating a web interface?
Or if it is posible to create GUI program for the users while using the same code from cobol...
Because i know that writing code to do same things in diferent places isnt good idea..
i mean the bussiness logic to exist in more than one places...

Comment: He wants you to upgrade the system to something new, but he doesn't want you to change the cobol code or use a database??

Comment: @Steve: Indeed...but there's some merit to the idea of doing the migration in stages.  Bring up the old system on a commodity HW+OS platform first, then worry about refactoring to a more modern architecture later.  Now get off my lawn! :-)

Comment: Actually he doesnt want me to do anything,he isnt sure.We were just talking..Because he has developed everything in the company he doesnt want anyone elses code etc.But he doesnt want to use a database or other language...But while searching at the internet found that COBOL is still used ,even with .NET.

Comment: What's your role in this?  If you're a consultant, I really hope you don't actually need this client, because they're very likely to woefully underestimate how much work is needed to deal with the system and the developer.  Be ready to walk away if possible, and do not, repeat DO NOT, make a fixed-priced bid that you yourself aren't completely comfortable with.

Comment: took you only hours to understand a COBOL System? Praise the Lord!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Run away!**

At least until your client comes around to using
a real database system to implement the order entry system. 
All transaction processing systems need
to ensure [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties
are maintained for every transaction. This is one of the fundamental reasons
why real data processing systems use databases. Not using a DBMS is
a sure formula for disaster (sooner or later).

Can COBOL be interfaced to a web service or a GUI type application? The answer
is definitely yes and it is not an uncommon practice. Making it happen
can be a more or less painful process depending on how the COBOL application
is structured. If it has a [Client/Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server) type structure,
then you only need to replace the Client side components with web/GUI
components, insert the appropriate middle-ware to connect to the server and you are pretty much done. 
If the COBOL application was developed as a
[big ball of mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud), then you are 
in for a rough ride. Since your client developed his system on a stand-alone platform by himself, I
am willing to bet serious money the "big ball of mud" model applies. Be prepared for the worst.

If this application only took "hours" instead of "months" to understand it doesn't sound
all that complex - you may find rebuilding it from scratch is a viable option. However,
don't underestimate the work in doing that either!

As for upgrading the AIX system or switching to Linux, I cannot help you.

Here are a couple of resources for COBOL on AIX that you might want to review:

- [COBOL AIX vendor information](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/cobol/aix/)
- [COBOL for AIX User's guide](http://publibfp.dhe.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/igyapg00.pdf)

If you choose to go the Linux route I would recommend checking out:

- [OpenCOBOL](http://www.opencobol.org/) COBOL to C translator
- [OpenCOBOL CGI programming](http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/#how-do-i-use-opencobol-for-cgi)

Your client expressed interest in MicroFocus COBOL. MicroFocus is probably the
largest COBOL vendor outside of the mainframe market. They have a very good reputation. 
[MicroFocus also supports web development on Linux platforms](http://www.microfocus.com/products/micro-focus-developer/micro-focus-cobol/cobol-UNIX-and-Linux/server-express.aspx)
and tends to have good support for IBM COBOL dialects which may be a consideration if migrating from AIX.

My final words of advice are to run away until your client wakes up to the
following facts:

- Data and transactions need to be managed using a real DBMS that supports ACID.
- tacking a web based order entry system onto a "ball of mud" is not a week-end project. It may require
  a complete refactoring and possibly a complete re-write of the existing system

BTW... If you want to retain a working relationship with this person, don't call his system 
a "ball of mud" even if it is one. He built this thing and probably
sees it as one of his children.

Comment: BTW... If you want to retain a working relationship with this person, don't call his system a "ball of mud" even if it is one. He built this thing and probably sees it as one of his children.
Thats true! hehe thats the way he thinks
I think that transactions handling wasnt a problem for 25 for him... So ...

Comment: just for history.I used open cobol with some modifications at compiler level. Programs names' -and still do- look like cli442.About 300 programs and more have as name a 3 char string and  numbers making no sense at all.For database i used a lame ISAM implementation with many bugs but couldnt find anything better however it works fine,only in concurrency has some problems(some fixed by me).As for web interface for orders we made an agreement with other companies to send a flat text file.(php script executes cobol prog)When i mentioned XML format they looked me like WTF everyone and screamed NO.

Answer (score 1):

AIX vs Linux -- Linux will be cheaper, top end AIX boxes are among the most powerful machines you can buy -- otherwise there is not much difference, most OSS software has been or can easily be ported to AIX.

You best strategy would be reuse the existing COBOL COPYBOOKs and write a COBOL program which reads the flat files and inserts into a more portbale format (XML,MySql imort file, file based database such as sqlite, or directly into a to the database at the web server).

The singular advantage of this approach is that there are commonly used COBOL ideosyncrasies  such as the character format numbers in "PIC BBBB99.99-", "REDEFINES" , " OCCURS DEPENDING ON ", " COMP SYNCHROISED" slack byte handling, packed decimal "COMP-3" format that are really really difficult to reproduce in other languages.

It should be noted that until very recently COBOL was one of the few languages that could do Arithimatic (as understood by accountants) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A Linux server with an installation of [TinyCOBOL](http://tiny-cobol.sourceforge.net/) might be an option.  I will keep
a close eye on [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/), in hopes of hearing the rest of the story...

Comment: Yeah,actually he is interested in microfocus cobol..I dont know if this works on linux,aix...
Anyways  my question was about reusing that code... as  an application server doesnt exist,or web services etc..In other words if it is possible to create a new distributed system using the old cobol code and not replacing it with something else

Answer (score 0):

Well yes that is the way he thinks... This system is his child for 25 years! And brough money to the company.Next week i'll see the source of one of his program...
Actually he made about 5 different programs...

You said that it can be interfaced,the question is how???
Using what? Now the system works through telnet... 
If the solution is creating telnet connections at the interfacing application ,and fetch data this way... i think that this is totally POOR..

Comment: Forget telnet. Web enbled applicaions
need to run on properly managed and secure web servers. You need to 
find a commercial Web Hosting service. The whole
application should run off of that (your local AIX or Linux box
then becomes a development/test platform). Other solutions
are more complex and expensive than what you are
probably looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach that I have used is to keep the COBOL core but expand around the edges. This fits in with "He wants to add the functionality to the web site of placing orders".

[Microfocus](http://www.microfocus.com/) provide a tool called Enterprise Server which allows COBOL to interact with web services. (It runs on both Linux and AIX).

If you have a COBOL program A and another COBOL program B and A calls B via the interface section, the tool allows you to expose B's interface section as a web service.

For program A, you then generate a client proxy and A can now call B via a web service.

Of course, because B now has a web service any other type of program (command line, Windows application, Java, ASP etc.) can now also call it.

Also, they have a product called COBOL.NET which runs inside Visual Studio and translates COBOL to MSIL. This means that you can then link in any .NET components.

So the approach is to keep the COBOL core but interface via web services and do new developments in any CLR compliant language (C#, VB etc.)

P.S. Be very careful of moving a COBOL system that uses big endian to a system that uses little endian and vice versa!